# Initial SQL database connection extremely slow

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I developed an asp.net mvc/angular website, which works fine on my local machine, however when uploaded to my GoDaddy shared hosting account, it takes FOREVER to create the initial database connection, when a user first tries to log into the site & I don't know how to fix (I know I can always move to a better host, but I'd like to see if there's any coding solutions I can try first & that it's not a problem I'm missing within my code).

Here's my site: whesearchreporting.com

Try logging in with any random login & you'll notice it takes about 15-20 seconds to receive the "Invalid Login" message (note: this will only affect the 1st person to hit the website.  It seems once a user attempts a connection, any add'l users who try to access the site, can log in instantly).

Here's my observations so far:

- This only affects the initial login (i.e. the initial database connection).  Once you're in, you can hit anything on the website, or even logout & log back in with no problem.
- If I log in on Computer A (which will take some time), I can then log in as a different user on Computer B almost instantly.
- I've read GoDaddy overloads their shared hosting servers, so I'm thinking this is the culprit, but not positive.

And here's some of my code:

Angular code:

```
 angular.module('dashboardApp', [])
.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $location, $window, LoginService) {
    $scope.IsLoggedIn = false;
    $scope.Message = '';
    $scope.Submitted = false;
    $scope.IsFormValid = false;

    $scope.AccountData = {
        Email: '',
        Password: ''
    };

    //Check is the form valid or not. 
    $scope.$watch('frmLogin.$valid', function (newVal) {            
        $scope.IsFormValid = newVal;
    });

    $scope.Login = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.Submitted = true;
        if ($scope.IsFormValid) {
            LoginService.GetUser($scope.AccountData).then(function (d) {
                if (d.data.Email != null) {
                    $scope.IsLoggedIn = true;
                    $window.location.href = "/Account/Dashboard";
                }
                else {
                    $scope.Message = "Invalid login";
                    $scope.loading = false;
                }
            });
        }
    };
})

.factory('LoginService', function($http) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetUser = function (d) {
        return $http({
            url: '/Home/UserLogin',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(d),
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        });
    };
    return fac;
 });
```

My `HomeController`:

```
public JsonResult UserLogin(Account account)
    {
        _accountService = new AccountService();
        if (_accountService.Login(account) != null)
        {
            //valid login credentials.  Set cookie & return client data
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(account.Email, false);
        }
        else
        {
            //invalid login.  Delete client data
            account = null;
        }
        return Json(account);
    }
```

My `AccountRepository` (`Login` method):

```
public string Login(Account a)
    {
        Account account = _accountRepository.GetAccountByEmail(a.Email);
        a.Password = a.Password.Encrypt(a.Email);

        if (account != null)
        {
            //password matches
            if(account.Password == a.Password)
            {
                return account.Email;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;             
    }
```

And finally, my db connection that grabs the account info:

```
 private readonly Connection _conn;

 public Account GetAccountByEmail(string email)
 {
        Account account;

        using (MySiteEntities db = _conn.GetContext())
        {
            account = (from c in db.Accounts
                      where c.Email.Equals(email)
                      select c).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return account;
}
```

Any idea why this initial connection is so slow & any thoughts on what I can do to improve the performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know if GoDaddy is using a Windows Server? Because this sounds like a issue with the IIS, it falls into an "hibernation" state after it isn't used for a while. You can change this setting but you can't turn it off as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shared Windows Server.

Comment: So this is what you are looking for: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b3258e7-261c-49a0-888c-0b3e68b2af13/preventing-iis-from-falling-into-sleep?forum=wcf

Comment: It was related to GoDaddy.  We switched hosting providers & have no slowdown issues now.